# Replication in multivariate logit in R

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multinomial-distribution, proportion, logit, log-linear

I am new to both logit models and GLMs, but I think one of those two model classes might be the correct analysis for my data set:

I am interested in comparing the composition of the diet of fish collected in 3 habitat types - thus "habitat" is a categorical predictor with 3 levels.

I want to test 2 types of null hypotheses:

1. That the relative proportions of food types A, B and C are the same among the 3 habitat types
2. Within each habitat, that the biomass of food is equally distributed between prey types A, B, and C.

In other words, to be able to make evaluations such as "The proportional composition of fish diet varied significantly among habitats.... The relative contribution of food A to fish diets was significantly higher in Habitat 1 than in Habitat 3... Food type A comprised a larger proportion if the diet of fish in Habitat 1 than did food type B."

The response data are proportions of food in categories A, B or C. Of course the proportions are bounded between 0 and 1 and within an individual fish the proportions sum to 1. The raw data are actually proportions, not counts of food items. I've taken the raw food item counts and used length/width relationships for the food types to yield biomass estimates for each food type - so the data in the "cells" for columns A, B and C are proportions of the total biomass in the gut of an individual fish.

I have analyzed multiple fish from each habitat type (22 from Habitat 1, 20 from Habitat 2, 8 from Habitat 3).

In reading on log-linear functions and multinomial logistic regressions, I now have myself thoroughly confused.

The elements of this application:

1. I have a definite predictor variable (habitat)
2. At the level of the individual fish (the replicates), the 3 food categories (A,B, and C) are not mutually exclusive.
3. Because of the biomass conversion, the raw data are proportions, not counts.

What it the best way to evaluate the null hypotheses for these data?

What post-hoc comparison approaches are appropriate?

General suggestions are welcome, suggestions tailored to R are even more welcome.